# JAssert library not incorporated in Spring Boot test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am testing a Spring Boot application using code from a tutorial. The tutorial describes the setup and configuration of a Spring Boot application, and also describes a test that uses `JAssert` calls in the following manner:

```
package hello;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SmokeTest {

  @Autowired
  private HomeController controller;

  @Test
  public void contexLoads() throws Exception {
    assertThat(controller).isNotNull();
  }
}
```

The test, unfortunately, will not compile in my `IDE`. The compilation is failing on the `assertThat()` method.

I am using Eclipse with Maven for my IDE. I have checked the Maven dependencies and see that the `JAssert` core library is included. Unfortunately, despite this the compiler can not seem to "find" the `assertThat()` call.

It fails to compile the test for that reason.

How do I get the test to utilize `JAssert` and find the calls to `JAssert` functions?

Comment: can you show the compile time error? and also i believe you have this as dependency `spring-boot-starter-test`

Comment: you code works for me without any issues

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an eclipse expert, but it seems like you have some configuration issue here.
If you're sure that the dependency appears in pom.xml in scope `test` then try to eliminate eclipse related issues by running the tests directly via maven:

```
mvn test
```

will do the job

If it runs sucessfully, then re-create eclipse configurations from pom.xml / re-import the project. 
If not, its a pom.xml related issue and has nothing to do with eclipse, you'll have to fix the pom or maven ecosystem. I suggest the following:

- go to the local repository and remove the dependency from the file system (manually, the whole directory, with jar, pom.xml and everything) and then rerun `mvn test`

Sometimes dependencies are downloaded corrupted and despite being defined correctly in pom.xml they do not really contain classes in a form that java/maven can read

Answer (score 0):

Actually:

It turns out that neither the Boot starter nor the IDE seems to find the necessary import declaration for the JAssert functions. Could it be because they are static?

In looking at some example code, I found in the code the import declaration for the assertThat() method. Usually, Eclipse would have suggested this declaration but it does not.

What is weird is that I put in the declaration by hand, and not only does this allow me to compile, but Eclipse, once the import is included, the code assistant makes proper assertThat() suggestions without problems!

There could be a bug somewhere, but that is beyond the scope of my particular problem.  My test now compiles without problems.

I hope someone looking at this can figure out why Elipse's code assist does not work for this particular library properly. I wouldn't be surprised to discover that there are other objects/libraries in Spring Boot that don't get properly handled by the code assistant.